# Duvida botão voltar ao abrir navegador webview

Tags: webview, android-webview

Boa tarde tenho a seguinte duvida utilizo um shouldOverrideUrlLoading para detectar quando determinado link é clicado dentro da minha webview para disparando no navegador do android, existe alguma maneira que ao abrir este link no navegador seja criado um botão voltar que volte para a webview? Pois este link serve somente para fazer uma validação e logo depois o usuario deve retornar para webview

[code]
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.sitemercado.com.br/valida")) {
                return true;

```
        }
        String valida = "https://www.sitemercado.com.br/valida";
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(valida));
        startActivity(i);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1Detectou", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return false;
    }
}); [/code]
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia,
Em um aplicativo (utilizando o WebView) que fazia um download no navegador, utilizei o código abaixo para retornar ao App quando pressionado o botão voltar, seria isso?

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (wv.canGoBack())
            wv.goBack();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();

```
}
```